# can data-target work with router

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm very new to front end development, and currently trying to resolve a problem with nav-tabs

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngRoute', 'ngTagsInput', 'http-auth-interceptor']);
var xeditableModule = angular.module('xeditable', []);

xeditableModule.run(function(editableOptions) {
    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; 
});


app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/foo',
        {
            controller: 'FooController',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/foo.html'
        })
        .when('/bar',
        {
            controller: 'Controller',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/bar.html'
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-target="#foo" data-toggle="tab" onclick="return false;">foo</a></li>
        <li><a data-target="#bar" data-toggle="tab" onclick="return false;">bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like my tabs to load the partials with controller logic, and I have tried with

```html
<a href="#bar" data-toggle="tab" onclick="return false;">bar</a></li>
```

It is also not working.

I would like to know what am I doing wrong. Please ask any questions if what I have describe isn't enough information as I am very new to front end development.

Comment: Bootstrap tabs and routing don't work together. Also since you're using the angular bootstrap library don't use a vanilla bootstrap tabs use the angular bootstrap tabs

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are saying. Can you provide an example on how it should work? I can't seem to get angular bootstrap library working either. Not sure what I am missing. I am using maven jars of bootstrap and angular.